# How to ensure an STL algorithm only iterates through a certain number of elements in a container?

Tags: c++

I need to return the bottom 10 elements in a map using a for_each algorithm. For some reason map iterators do not have random access so I cannot use:

```
std::for_each(std::map.end(), std::map.end()-10, <lambda>);
```

I can use the -- operator on the iterators, but I'd rather not use ten of those!

So can someone let me know if there is a way to specify that the algorithm should only consider 10 of the elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `auto x = your_map.end();` [`std::advance(x, -10);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance).

Note that as you have the iterators now, however, that won't do much good. You need the beginning of the range first -- if you use `whatever.end()` as the first parameter to `for_each`, it won't work correctly.

If you want to iterate through the map in reverse order, you could use:

```
auto s your_map.rbegin();
advance(s, 10);

std::for_each(s, your_map.rend(), ...);
```

Comment: Does advance essentially just call -- or ++ the specified number of times on the given iterator? I need to know because there is a chance that the map contains less than 10 elements, and it will need to not perform the lambda on a null pointer.

Comment: @wesrobin: I don't think it does any checking, so you'd want `if (your_map.size() > 10) ...`.

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 you can use [`std::advance(iter, dist)`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/advance.html) instead of calling `++` or `--` ten times. To go forward, pass positive `dist`; to go backward, pass a negative `dist`:

```
auto ten_before(map.end());
std::advance(ten_before, -1);
std::for_each(std::map.end(), ten_before, -10), <lambda>);
```

Comment: Thank you, so I can use
`std::for_each(std::map.end(), std::advance(std::map.end(), -10), <lambda>);`
? Also, are the algorithms clever enough to see that if the second iterator is less than the first, they should go backwards, or should I be trying to use a reverse iterator?

Comment: @wesrobin You need to define a separate variable for it, because `std::advance` changes its argument; its return type is `void`.

Comment: @wesrobin: as already noted in my answer: no, you need to arrange the iterators correctly.

Comment: Okay, gotcha. Thanks for the swift answers!

Comment: `advance` is also in C++03.

Answer (score 2):

`std::advance` as the other answers recommend will work. But in C++11 it's more convenient to use [`std::prev`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev), which returns the resulting iterator instead of changing the given iterator, so it can be used in a one-liner:

```
std::for_each(std::prev(mymap.end(), 10), mymap.end(), func);
```

Note: I fixed the order of iterators above, you had the iterators backwards in your example.

If you want to iterate the last 10 items in reverse order, starting from the last element, you can use reverse iterators and [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next):

```
std::for_each(mymap.rbegin(), std::next(mymap.rbegin(), 10), func);
```